# How to check the arm version of an object file compiled for iOS ?

Tags: ios

I have an object file compiled for iOS. I try to use file command to see any information about the arm version, but no data about it:

```
qty:ffmpeg_ios qrtt1$ file cmdutils.o
cmdutils.o: Mach-O object arm
```

If I want to know the arm version, how can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lipo for this I believe.

`lipo -info cmdutils.o`

Comment: That's what I want. Thank you :)